# Faceted Search in Coldfusion and SQL?

Tags: sql, search, coldfusion

I'm working on a faceted search in Coldfusion and SQL. I've tried creating a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Turbos 
WHERE
  PartNumber LIKE '%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%' 
  OR PartDescription LIKE '%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%' 
  AND (PumpingSpeed BETWEEN #minimum# AND #URL.speed#) 
  AND InletFlange LIKE '#URL.inlet#' 
  AND Bearing LIKE '#URL.bearing#' 
  AND Condition LIKE '#URL.condition#'
```

The problem is the server is returning rows that don't contain EVERY piece of data I'm supplying. How can I select ONLY those rows which contain all the criteria?

Comment: don't forget to use <cfqueryparam>

Comment: Scott, have you considered what happens when someone puts, for example, `?&condition=';DROP TABLE Turbos; SELECT 'Haha` onto the URL for that page? **Use cfqueryparam!**

Comment: I'm planning on using the CfQueryParams when I finally get it working, but thanks for the reminder to secure against injection.

Comment: @Scott can you post some example results and what you expected instead?

Comment: cfoutput the SQL to see what query it is trying to run, and verify that it looks ok.

Comment: This is an ambiguous question, and consequently impossible to answer as nobody is really sure what you are trying to get your query to do.

Can you just say in plain English what you want your SQL to do...e.g.

if only partnumber supplied .. only search on that
else if partdescription and one or more of pumpingspeed, inletflange .. fuzzy match where all match

and give us some sample data rows, say 5

+1 @Lucas

Comment: +1 to clarifying the question. (It is unlikely this has any bearing on the results, but what is the point of using LIKE without wildcards "%"? If it is an equality comparison you are after, just use equals ie ... AND Condition = '#URL.condition#' )

Comment: I'm trying to create a faceted search: i.e. like newegg's or amazon's. As far as I'm seeing, the only way to do this is to use CFIF tags to add the SQL for each search criteria as necessary. Trouble is, I have no idea how to insert the AND statements between an arbitrary number of LIKE statements. Maybe I should have asked that instead! O:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just wrap the OR bit in brackets:

```
(PartNumber LIKE '%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%' OR PartDescription LIKE '%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%') AND...
```

at the moment you have A or B and C which is being read as A or (B and C). You want (A or B) and C.

And make sure you use cfqueryparam as suggested above.

Comment: Well, that worked... sort of. Now the search returns nothing, even when I specify all values.

Comment: Start isolating it down by removing the AND clauses one by one to see which is throwing away the results you expect to see. In particular I'd just leave the PartNumber and PartDescription in there to make sure it's matching on the Parts you'd expect.

Comment: @Aidan's suggestion is a good approach. BTW: Is there any chance your database is case sensitive (or you are using a QoQ)?

Comment: Aiden: I don't think it's a particular clause that's the problem. (See my comment on the first reply.)

Leigh: My database is an access database that will be migrated to mySQL shortly, so there's no case sensitivity.

Comment: Could you supply an example row you would expect returned along with the criteria you're using. Remember, without any conditions all data would be returned - you expect some data and you're getting none. The only sound conclusion is that one or more conditions are limiting rows that you expect to be in the result.

Comment: Also, just noticed that you're using LIKE on most conditions but don't actually have % in there anywhere. Maybe that's why you're nit seeing the results you expect.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly why! It works great now, thanks again! :)

Comment: @Scott - Interesting. I had mentioned the LIKE condition in another comment, but had not thought it would skew the results. Of course I do not normally use LIKE in that manner .. so that is good to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess really, but change

> ...'%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%' **OR**
>   PartDescription ...

to

> ...'%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%' **AND**
>   PartDescription ...

**edit**
or are you saying some have null values?

**post comment edit**
Imagine for example that `InletFlange` is empty for your part, and the user didn't put it in their search.
Then `InletFlange LIKE '#URL.inlet#'` will compare `"" LIKE ""`, which is of course true, so the product shows up.

There are many ways to solve this.  For example

1. Default the search criteria to "N/A" or something
2. Default the column in the database in a similar fashion.
3. something along the lines of `AND NOT ISNULL(InletFlange,'')==''` for each criteria

Comment: If an empty string ('') is null, then yes, I do have null values.

Comment: no empty string is not null, but for your question, close enough.  I will edit my answer...

Comment: There are no empty fields in the database, that's what puzzles me; the items are getting pulled anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answers:

> **Leigh**: +1 to clarifying the question. (It is
>   unlikely this has any bearing on the
>   results, but what is the point of
>   using LIKE without wildcards "%"? If
>   it is an equality comparison you are
>   after, just use equals ie ... AND
>   Condition = '#URL.condition#' )

You were quite right, I was missing the percent symbols in my LIKE comparisons (DUH!). I removed them earlier thinking they were the problem, but they weren't, this was:

> **Aiden:** just wrap the OR bit in brackets:

```
(PartNumber LIKE '%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%' OR PartDescription LIKE '%#trim(SearchCriteria)#%') AND...
```

Thank you Aiden!

Comment: Well .. that makes much more sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

While this isnt an answer to your question - you might want to consider using a dedicated search solution such as Solr (which is included with CF9). Its a more powerful fulltext solution than just raw SQL and includes facetting